# Is there an algorithm to cover a partite set of a bipartite graph with disjoint 6-cycles?

Tags: algorithms, bipartite-graphs

Does an algorithm exist that finds a vertex-disjoint set of 6-cycles on a bipartite graph that covers one of the partite sets or determines that one does not exist?

I've found some papers on related subjects, specifically *Disjoint Small Cycles in Graphs and Bipartite Graphs* (Ma, Gao 2013), which gives conditions for being able to decompose bipartite graphs into disjoint 6-cycles and 6-paths or quadrilaterals, but I haven't found a useful algorithm for checking if a disjoint 6-cycle cover exists. Does anyone know if such an algorithm exists?

Thank you.

Comment: If a vertex(!)-disjoint decomposition exists, finding it should be trivial, shouldn't it?

Comment: At the risk of feeling stupid, how is it trivial? I don't see an efficient algorithm. Would it be similar to finding a matching? Also, I changed the original question because the question I wrote was different from the one I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, I think, NP-complete. Here is a tentative proof of the hardness (feel free to polish it). The reduction is from Partition into Triangles.

Given a graph G=(V,E) let Subd(G) be obtained from G by subdividing each edge exactly once. Note that Subd(G) is bipartite, with its two partite sets corresponding to V and E, respectively.

Assume G can be partitioned into vertex-disjoint triangles. To any such partition we can associate a set of vertex-disjoint cycles of length six in Subd(G) that cover the partite set V (simply add the vertices that correspond to the edges in these triangles).

For the converse direction, assume that G has maximum degree at least three (otherwise, G is a disjoint union of cycles and paths, and it is easy to check whether G can be partitioned into vertex-disjoint triangles)

1) Let e = uv be an edge of G and let xe be the corresponding vertex in Subd(G). Then, in any cycle of length six in Subd(G) that contains xe, the two neighbours of xe must be u and v. In particular, suppose a vertex v of G is incident to three edges e1, e2, e3. We cannot have two vertex-disjoint cycles of length six in Subd(G) that contain xe1, xe2, xe3.

2) The above implies that if there exists a collection of vertex-disjoint cycles of length six that cover one partite set of Subd(G), this partite set must be V (i.e., it cannot be E). Then, it is easy to see that we can associate to such a collection a partition of G into triangles.

Since Partition into Triangles is NP-complete, so is your problem.